# Unexpected change in Wpf DataGridTemplateColumn and ComboBox as CellEditingTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, wpfdatagrid

The following is a demo project to show our actual problem.

Suppose we have the following data:

```
public class Person
{
    public PersonType PersonType { get; set; }
    public Job Job { get; set; }
}

public class PersonType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
}

public class Job
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and sample data:

```
public class TestData
{
    public static List<PersonType> PersonTypes = new List<PersonType>
    {
        new PersonType
        {
            Name = "Person1",
            Jobs = new List<Job>
            {
                new Job{Name = "Development"},
                new Job{Name = "Testing"}
            }
        },
        new PersonType
        {
            Name = "Person2",
            Jobs = new List<Job>
            {
                new Job{Name = "Design"},
                new Job{Name = " Analysis"}
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Now we have a data grid that is used to view and manage data:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="People" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="PersonTypes" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="JobsData" />
</Window.Resources>
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource People}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PersonType.Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding PersonType, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource PersonTypes}}" 
                                        DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectionChanged="PersonTypeChanged" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Job.Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource JobsData}}"
                                        DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValue="{Binding Job}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        People.Source = new List<Person>();
        PersonTypes.Source = TestData.PersonTypes;
    }

    public CollectionViewSource People { get { return Resources["People"] as CollectionViewSource; } }
    public CollectionViewSource PersonTypes { get { return Resources["PersonTypes"] as CollectionViewSource; } }
    public CollectionViewSource JobsData { get { return Resources["JobsData"] as CollectionViewSource; } }

    private void PersonTypeChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var personType = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem as PersonType;
        if (personType == null)
        {
            JobsData.Source = null;
        }
        else
        {
            JobsData.Source = personType.Jobs;
        }
    }
}
```

In short, when the `PersonType` is selected for a `Person` row, the `Job` column should be filled with the possible jobs for that `PersonType` to choose from.

Now the problem: when we change the 'PersonType' in a row, Job of the other rows will be affected (filtered). It seems that `CellEditingTemplate` not only applied to editing mode, it is still there and functional, but not shown. So when the `ItemsSource` of the `ComboBox` is changed, it will affect all rows.

How can we fix this?

Comment: Have you tried binding the `Jobs` ComboBox to `PersonType.Jobs` instead of "JobsData" collection?

Comment: In this sample I can, but in the real one, this will be quite difficult and will break an otherwise good design.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you use the same JobsData CollectionViewSource for all the rows. If you don't want to change your design I'd suggest caching the cell editing event and update the JobsData there.